# does it make sense to put two convolutional layers sequentially after each other without an activation function

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am working with one model, here part of it:

```
...
nn.Conv2d(1, 1 * filters_multiplier, kernel_size=(3, 1)),
nn.Conv2d(1 * filters_multiplier, 6 * filters_multiplier, kernel_size=(1, 3)),

# no activation layer

nn.Conv2d(6 * filters_multiplier, 6 * filters_multiplier, kernel_size=(3, 1)),
nn.Conv2d(6 * filters_multiplier, 12 * filters_multiplier, kernel_size=(1, 3)),
nn.MaxPool2d((3, 3), stride=(2, 2)),
...
```

I understand that layers 1-2 and 3-4 are just convs(3,3) made for easier calculations (3x1 and 1x3 is 6 operations and 3x3 is 9). But does it make sense to put two convolutional layers sequentially after each other without an activation function or it is just a mistake? I mean between convs 1-2 and 3-4 (in commented place). I thought that a convolution followed by a convolution is just a convolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of adding an activation at the end of a layer is to make sure that your model can learn non-linear functions. Without activation, you will just be doing linear regression. It is the activation functions that give neural networks the power to model any function given enough depth ( [Universal Approximation Theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem)

Thus it is perfectly fine not to add activations, but then you would lose on non-linearities.

If you use a linear activation function or alternatively if you don't have an activation function then no matter how many layers your neural network has, all your model is doing is just computing a linear
activation function so you might as well not have any hidden layers. (See the figure below for proof). The purpose of depth loses its essence.
[image: Non-linear Activation]

For details, you can refer to this video by Andrew Ng https://youtu.be/NkOv_k7r6no.

#### For Convolutional Neural Network -

Well, this works the same for CNN and we don't need to prove it separately (one can do obviously). As convolutions are themselves a constraint. It just restricts the kernels to a particular spatial location, hence preserves spatial properties. A convolutional layer is really just a more restricted version of a fully connected (FC) layer. This is why you can implement convolutions using an FC layer and vice versa — they’re fundamentally the same thing. [ Source and for further details refer  - https://machinethink.net/blog/object-detection/ & https://youtu.be/bNb2fEVKeEo ]

Comment: Wait, interesting to see if you can prove this with convolutions as well.

Comment: @Ivan we don't need to check my updated answer.